# Select next rows that have ID.length > 0 in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using only jQuery, how would I select the next rows in a table with an ID length > 0?

In my code, I'm using a hybrid of jQuery and javascript. And it works fine. However, I'd like it to be all in jQuery.

```
var rowsWithIds = new Array();
var rows = $(myTable).nextAll("tr");
for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    if(rows[i].id.length > 0)
        rowsWithIds[rowsWithIds.length] = rows[i];
}
```

Perhaps, the solution might look like:

```
var rowsWithIds = $(myTable).nextAll("tr").has("some selector");
```

or

```
var rowsWithIds = $(myTable).nextAll("tr and some selector");
```

Let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gets all table-rows with an id, removing all that have an empty id:

```
var rowsWithIDs = $("tr[id]").not("[id='']");
```

Comment: Then the final answer is: var rowsWithIds = $(myTable).nextAll("tr[id]").not("[id='']");

Answer (score 2):

change

```
var rows = $(myTable).nextAll("tr");
```

to

```
var rows = $(myTable).nextAll("tr[id]");
```

it will select all `tr` with id (*you should not use id with no value*)

Comment: Note, this will include `<tr id=''></tr>` too.

Comment: Touche!  I did not test that scenario. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: @Jonathan, that is true .. and hence the disclaimer that he should not use id without an actual value ..